# Library dependencies System.Collections 4.0.0 installing failed

Tags: c#, .net

I made library which is nuget availiable. Let's call it A. Now I would like to create other solution which will use this library and extend it's API by adding fluent api.

My library project type (A) is dll portable with targets: .Net Framework 4.5, Windows 8, ASP.NET Core 1.0

Now, I was trying to create another project in different solution(let's call it B) with same targets (still .dll) However, i can't get manage to make it work. When installing A lib by nuget, it throws:

> Could not install package 'System.Collections 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

How to fix it?